# Poincaré Index of a periodic orbit

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I am trying to formalize the following proof on Perko's Differential Equations and Dynamical Systems, which says that a periodic orbit has index +1.

[image]

My only problem is trying to prove that the map $g$ is continuous on $T$. Geometrically it seems obvious, and I am trying to prove it using limits, but I do not get anything. The following figure (also from Perso's book) is a nice illustration:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

All follows from the definition of the vector field $\bf u$. For example, on the line $s=t$ you have
$$
\lim_{t\to s^+}\frac{x(t)-x(s)}{\|x(t)-x(s)\|}=\lim_{t\to s^+}\frac{\frac{x(t)-x(s)}{t-s}}{\left\|\frac{x(t)-x(s)}{t-s}\right\|}=\frac{x'(s)}{\|x'(s)\|}={\bf u}(x(s)).
$$

The proof and figures are copied from Coddington and Levinson's book, really the best book there is on this particular topic.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, you are only approaching the line $s=t$ from "above", but I think we need to compute that limit aproaching from everywhere (for example on a diagonal)

Comment: Of course, but on the diagonal it is trivial.

Comment: I mean on something like, on the point $(1/2,1/2)$, the line $y=-1/4+3/2*x$ aproaching $(1/2,1/2)$ from the right

Comment: That is a very particular case of my answer.