# Singularity and periodic orbit in ODE systems

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, stability-in-odes

I was learning qualitative theory of ODEs and was confused about the relation between the existence of singularity and periodic orbits.(We care about flows generated by $C^1$ vector fields from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to itself)

Namely, is it true that if a system have periodic orbit, then there is a singular point?

Or in general how to determine whether a system have periodic orbits or not, or the behavior (i.e. Lyapunov Stability, etc.) of singularities, or the relationship between them?

I know the Poincare-Bendixson theorem states that if the orbit is bounded and the limit set is without singularity then it is a periodic orbit, but what about in other conditions, is there some regular method to analyze it?

Comment: OK for the particular question in the second paragraph now I know it's CORRECT (I found a claim on my tutor's notes) but still don't why.

Comment: I was thinking that maybe firstly, the periodic orbit condition bounds every other orbit "inside" the periodic one; secondly, the none-singularity condition can serve as a fact that every point have a transversal over it, but I can't see if these observation make any help :(

Answer (score 0):

If you have a periodic orbit then it must enclose a critical point. This is because the [Poincare Index](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1697835/poincar%C3%A9-index-of-a-periodic-orbit) of a periodic orbit must be equal to 1.

In general, proving the existence of a periodic orbit is highly non-trivial. There are some techniques that may assist you in finding them (conserved quantities, integral curves, Poincare-Bendixon) but this is in general difficult to do.

If you're looking at Poincare-Bendixon, be careful in $\mathbb{R}^n$ as this does not hold in dimensions greater than $2$.

Hopefully this somewhat answers your question!